# Grouping a "other" group with R and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, sql

I'm trying to figure out, how to best deal with an "other" group or how to create one. I'm using R and ggplot2.

## Data

As an example: I'm analyzing the german Bundestagswahl (general election, every four years). There are at least 38 parties, that voters could vote for in 2009 (see [bundeswahlleiter.de](http://www.bundeswahlleiter.de/de/bundestagswahlen/BTW_BUND_09/ergebnisse/bundesergebnisse/) for numbers). Let's say, that I have an mysql database `bundestagswahl` with a column `party` and a column `votes`. Now I want to do some plots using ggplot.

Normally I would write a sql query with votes per party. Next I would tell ggplot2 to draw a geom_bar. This would draw me at least 38 bars.

### Now my question

How can I create an "other" group, e.g. all parties, which have less then 5% of all votes to not clutter up the graph? This way I would have only 5 bars (=less clutter).

Of course I could write my sql-query to ignore parties, that have not at least 5%, but this way my counts wouldn't sum up to 100%. Over 6 % of all votes went to parties, which didn't made it into the parlament.

How would you do it? Write another sql query? Or using reshape? Or some other way?

### Update

To make it a bit clearer, what I want to do, here is a fake dataset of six parties (names A, B, C, D, E and F) and there number of votes:

```
> party <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
> votes <- c(1000, 2000, 5, 1500, 15, 20)
> df <- data.frame(party, votes)
> df
  party votes
1     A  1000
2     B  2000
3     C     5
4     D  1500
5     E    15
6     F    20
```

Now I want to do two things:

1. relabel all parties, which have less then 100 votes to "other".
2. add up those "other" parties to one entry.

Wanted outcome:

```
  party votes
1     A  1000
2     B  2000
3 other    40
4     D  1500
```

How do I do this? Is maybe `combine_factor` of the packages `reshape` an option?

Comment: perhaps I am missing something but why can't you determine, in R, which groups have frequencies of less than 5% and then relabel them all as 'other' and re-calculate the frequencies?

Comment: @Macro: That's probably the answer: how would I relabel groups inside my dataframe?

Comment: @Kevin It is already answered, so there is no sense in moving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would probably approach the problem:

```
df <- within(df, other.group <- ifelse(votes > 100, as.character(party), "Other"))
df <- within(df, relevel(factor(other.group), "Other"))

ggplot(df, aes(other.group, votes)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Answer (score 2):

This will first assign "other" to any group with less then 5% of the votes and then give you the aggregated totals. The non-"other" groups are just their original values, while the "other" group gets summed.

```
df$party2 <- ifelse(df$votes/sum(df$votes) < 0.05, 
                    "other", 
                    as.character(df$party))
df.aggr <- aggregate(votes ~ party2, data = df, FUN = sum)
```

Which gives:

```
  party2 votes
1      A  1000
2      B  2000
3      D  1500
4  other    40
```

Comment: I think it should be `aggr` instead of `df.aggr`. Other then that, this works great.